# Not Able to Add US Card in Android Pay App in India

Tags: android, payment, android-pay

I am implementing Android Pay in my app. For that i have followed all steps in android guide.
[Android Pay Guide Link](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/tutorial)
|

My Android Code is ready but i am unable to add card to Android Pay app to proceed further.

I have added US Card Details of CITI Bank but it is not accepting card.

Even i have added 2-3 US card details still i am stucked.

Can Anyone tell me how can i test that or any sandbox environment or any testing card details

Please help, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Nikhilesh,

Unfortunately direct answer to your question is NO.
But if you are not interested specifically in Android Pay for Indian customers, but want to test NFC based in-app payments, you may think of trying PayZApp from HDFC,
http://www.hdfcbank.com/htdocs/PayZapp/index.html

Vinay

Answer (score 0):

According to [Citi's website](https://www.citi.com/credit-cards/creditcards/citi.action?ID=citi-android-pay&intc=2~1~52~3~092215~5~Android_Pay_2015~SignOn_NON_Cookied_Tab3):

"The following Citi® branded consumer cards are not eligible for use with Android Pay at this time: ATM cards, American Express cards, and Citi® / AAdvantage® cards. Citi® business and professional cards are not eligible."

Could you be using one that isn't compatible? You can also check [here](https://support.google.com/androidpay/answer/6314169) for other card options.

There's no sandbox testing, so you might want to just submit a debug test APK to their support team for review. You won't be able to complete any live transactions anyways without production access.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Android pay into Testable environment and Add card in Android Pay in India:

- Install Android Pay apk from apkmirror website. Make sure you use
     correct apk variant.

http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-pay/

or

use TunnelBear(Change VPN) app to download Android Pay App in India

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tunnelbear.android

- Turn on Sandbox Mode by executing following commands from command
  prompt

  ```
  adb shell
  cd /sdcard/Download;
  rm ­-f android_pay_env_override_*;
  touch android_pay_env_override_sandbox;
  ```

[image: enter image descriptionhere]

- Reboot the phone
- Launch the Android Pay app and add following test credit card: Card
     Number: 4622 9431 2999 9943 Expiry: 12/17 CVV: 125 Enter other
     details like address and proceed. So that card is added
     successfully.

Comment: I tried the above but didn't work for some reason.  I get as far as "Card Issuer Terms & Conditions" , hit "Accept.", see "Your bank is verifying your card" but then get "Your card couldn't be added"

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Please include hyphen (-) before 'f'. rm ­-f android_pay_env_override_*; Have you tried all commands successfully.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I think android pay is not converted on sandbox environment properly. We have to run all commands successfully.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I am getting same error "Your card couldn't be added". please help. any solution?

Comment: can any one reply?

Comment: @pratikbhiyani Have you done wtih all steps properly? I think something would be missing in configuration.

Comment: Hey Garima thanks for reply. Yes I followed all commands and even i can see this file "android_pay_env_override_sandbox" in download folder of android mobile sdcard but it's still not working.